# Python SQL insert is failing

Tags: python, sql

I have 5 character fields in my SQL database, but I am unable to insert rows into the table. I have no problem when I do in Access Database.

Here is the code for my Insert statement and the error I am getting:

```
f1=hostname; f2=p.Caption; f3=p.Version; f4="1998-10-01";f5="2018-11-01"
print(f1,'--',f2,'--',f3,'--',f4,'--',f5)
sql = "INSERT INTO software VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
cursor.execute(sql, {f1,f2,f3,f4,f5})
```

Error Message:

> cursor.execute(sql, (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5)) pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The
>   SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 5 parameters were supplied',
>   'HY000')

Comment: Have a look at https://www.python-course.eu/sql_python.php

Comment: how many columns your table has ?

Comment: one auto generate Identity column, and 5 other columns.

Comment: When I use following code: w = wmi.WMI()
for p in w.Win32_Product():
 f1=hostname; f2=p.Caption; f3=p.Version; f4="1998-10-01";f5="2018-11-01"
 sql_command = """INSERT INTO software (computer, software, version, date_installed, date_checked) VALUES (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5);"""
cursor.execute(sql_command)

conn.commit()   I get [SQL Server]Invalid column name 'f1'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW) error

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using pyodbc, the parameter marker is a `?`:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO software VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```